# How to limit the picture size took from IMAGE_CAPTURE intent

Tags: android, image, android-intent, photo, image-size

I use

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");  
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(getSomePath()+"temp.jpg"))); 
//intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);  
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

to get a picture and the saved picture returns as full-size.

But I want to get a limited picture, like 800*640, because on different devices I get different sizes, and I don't need that big picture.

I notice that there is a [EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT in MediaStore](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT) , but I can't find how to use it, what parameter should be set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question.

Finally I found that's because different manufacturers customize their Rom, including the Camera app, so the best way is not to call the default camera app, instead we can write a activity use `hardware.camera` to take picture. There are a lot of examples for this around the Internet too.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT used for video limit in bytes.